# Pandas: timestamp to datetime

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have dataframe and column with dates looks like

```
 date
 1476329529    
 1476329530    
 1476329803 
 1476329805 
 1476329805  
 1476329805
```

I use `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`
to convert that, but I'm get strange result

```
 date 
 1970-01-01 00:00:01.476329529   
 1970-01-01 00:00:01.476329530   
 1970-01-01 00:00:01.476329803  
 1970-01-01 00:00:01.476329805    
 1970-01-01 00:00:01.476329805   
 1970-01-01 00:00:01.476329805
```

Maybe I did anything wrong

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This looks look epoch timestamps which is number of seconds since 1st January 1970 :

```
In [71]:
pd.to_datetime(df['date'], unit='s')
​
Out[71]:
0   2016-10-13 03:32:09
1   2016-10-13 03:32:10
2   2016-10-13 03:36:43
3   2016-10-13 03:36:45
4   2016-10-13 03:36:45
5   2016-10-13 03:36:45
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Hello, for me this is still defaulting 1970. What is the problem?

Comment: check your units.  pd now defaults to nanoseconds if you don't specify units

Answer (score 2):

Something like this maybe:

```
import datetime
date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1476329529)
date
# gives
# datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 13, 5, 32, 9)

str(date) # '2016-10-13 05:32:09'
```