# How do i convert int64 to timestamp

Tags: python, timestamp

```
import pandas as pd
import urllib
from pandas import DataFrame, Series
import datetime

url = 'https://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/GOOG/chartdata;type=quote;range=10d/csv'
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, './data/goog.csv')
GOOG= DataFrame(pd.read_csv("goog.csv"))

 GOOG['Timestamp']= datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(GOOG['Timestamp']).strptime('%Y-%m-%d :%H:%M:%S)
```

In this code i was able to download intraday data off yahoo finance and then save to a csvfile. However, the dates are dtype=int64 and I'm having trouble converting it to a timestamp. I'm not sure why i can't do so.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas: timestamp to datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40038169/pandas-timestamp-to-datetime)

Comment: you're missing a quote `...%Y-%m-%d :%H:%M:%S'`<- **HERE**. Also, the `csv` file isn't properly formatted.

Answer (score 1):

1 - The `csv` isn't properly formatted to be imported into `pandas`
2 - We need to convert the `timestamp` to datetime using `to_datetime` and `unit="s"` as argument.

Here's a working example:

```
import requests
import re
import pandas as pd
from io import BytesIO

symbol = "GOOG"
days = 10

url = 'https://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/{}/chartdata;type=quote;range={}d/csv'.format(symbol, days)
csv = requests.get(url).text
headers = re.findall(r"values:(.*?)\s+", csv, re.IGNORECASE)[0]
csv = re.sub(r".*volume:.*?\s", "", csv, 0, re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL)
csv = "{}\n{}".format(headers,csv)
GOOG = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(csv), sep=",")
GOOG['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(GOOG['Timestamp'], unit="s")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you timestamp is Unix time, then simply use:

In case of seconds Unix time:

```
pd.to_datetime(timestamp, unit='s')
```

Or in case of nano seconds Unix time:

```
pd.to_datetime(timestamp, unit='ns')
```

---

The result:

```
GOOG['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(GOOG['Timestamp'], unit='s')
```